# Need help to run a function on contract but get Big Number error

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, cpp-ethereum

```
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi)
var myContractInstance = myContract.at(address)
myContractInstance.func.call()
```

Get Error:
    new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:

EDIT:
if anyone comes across this, the problem was that the blockchain was not completely in sync.

Comment: could you share the contract?

Comment: ----------
the abi and address are there.. Im guessing the difficulty is not getting a decent reply from the actual contract response